# Spring Data + JPA how to avoid loading a column

Tags: spring-data-jpa

i have a table with 6 columns and one of them is a CLOB column, during search against this table i don't want to bring this column data but when user requests for the details then ill load it, how do i achieve this with Spring Data JPA, I try to use Projections + MetaModel Object with no help

Comment: Try annotating the field with `@Basic(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)`

Comment: I have it but i do conversion at the Web tier from Entity Object to Resource object, so how do i avoid it

Comment: Don't call getter for that field, because doing so will trigger the query to fetch CLOB data. Also, note that this might not work, different JPA implementations handle this in different ways.

Comment: i am using a ResourceAssembler's OrderResource toResource(Order entity), as this method is used for both Details call and Query, here i have to call getter

Answer (score 1):

I did this by moving two columns into a separate table, but even if you can't touch the database, you can always map two different entities to different columns of the same table.

Heavyweight child entity:

```java
@Entity
public class RawImage implements Serializable {
    // other properties
    private String type;
    private byte[] data;
}
```

Lightweight parent entity:

```java
@Entity
public class Model implements Serializable {
    // other properties (ID etc.)

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_image_id")
    private RawImage image;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_thumb_id")
    private RawImage thumb;
}
```

This means the image/thumb data isn't loaded by default, and I just added a fetch when I do need them with something like the following:

```java
String jpql = "select m from Model m join fetch m.image i";
```

There are [other techniques described in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2561041/344029) but they weren't as clean as I think this simple solution is.

Comment: what is your jpa implementation? do you believe that one-to-one lazy works or checked it by tracing real sql queries?

Comment: @SimonLogic Hibernate. I certainly did check! I just did this same thing with Spring 6.0.11 and Hibernate 6.2.7.Final and it still works.